# How to find Last Week entries and This Week entries from postgres tables

Tags: postgresql

I want to find the LastWeek entries from postgres table with cycle from Monday to Sunday (both inclusive) For eg - if I query the data today i.e on 2020/07/26 (or say if i query data on any date between 2020/07/20 to 2020/07/26) i should get the data from 2020/07/13 to 2020/07/19
Query:

```
Select user, date_sent 
from users 
where date_sent between (SELECT current_date - cast(extract(dow from current_date) as int) - 6) 
                    and (SELECT current_date - cast(extract(dow from current_date) as int) + 1)
```

Similarly I want to find the This Week entries week starting from Monday and ending on present date. For eg - If I query the data today i.e on 2020/07/26 I should get the data from 2020/07/20 to 2020/07/26. If i query on 2020/07/24 then I should get 2020/07/20 to 2020/07/24
Query:

```
select user, date_sent 
from users 
where date_sent >= date_trunc('week', current_date) 
  and date_sent <= date_trunc('day',current_date+1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

For "this week":

```
select user, date_sent 
from users 
where date_sent >= date_trunc('week', current_date) 
  and date_sent < date_trunc('week', current_date) + interval '1 week';
```

For last week it's quite similar:

```
select user, date_sent 
from users 
where date_sent >= date_trunc('week', current_date) - interval '1 week'
  and date_sent < date_trunc('week', current_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your desired results are inconsistent. In your description, before your initial query you state:

> if I query the data today i.e on 2020/07/26 (or say if i query data on
> any date between 2020/07/20 to 2020/07/26) i should get the data from
> 2020/07/13 to 2020/07/19

But after that query you state:

> If I query the data today i.e on 2020/07/26 I should get the data from
> 2020/07/20 to 2020/07/26.

***You cannot have both.*** 

Assuming the latter to be correct and assuming ISO-8601 week definition, then your request can be re-phased as:

> Given a specified date, if that date falls in the same week as the
> current date then return the dates from the start of the week to the
> specified date, inclusive. If the specified date does not fall in the
> current week return the dates return the dates from Monday on or prior
> to the specified date through Sunday on or after the specified date, inclusive.

The following implements that.

```
with targets (for_week_containing_date
             ,from_week_start
             ,iso_from_week
             ,iso_this_week) as 
     ( select &for_week_containing_date
            , date_trunc('week', &for_week_containing_date)
            , extract(week from &for_week_containing_date)
            , extract(week from now())
            ) 
select user, date_sent
  from user_days
 cross join targets 
 where 1=1
   and date_sent >= from_week_start
   and date_sent <= case when iso_from_week = iso_this_week
                         then for_week_containing_date
                         else from_week_start + interval '6 days'
                    end 
   ;
```

Since I do not care much for substitution variables this would need bound variables from a script, or wrap wrap it in an SQL function. See example of that [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=34f6277c2d843ba492652781a5ef7314). Also note the last 2 queries, make sure you are ok with and understand what's happening around year end.  You may need to make end of year/ begin of year adjustments. The results are not from being in a function, but result from ISO-8601 definitions. **End of year/Begin year checking is needed any time you deal with date ranges.**